# Symfony 6 + Doctrine - How to configure Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\OCI8\Middleware\InitializeSession?

Tags: oracle, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, dbal

The `Doctrine\DBAL\Event\Listeners\OracleSessionInit` was deprecated in DBAL 3.5 (https://github.com/doctrine/dbal/blob/3.5.x/UPGRADE.md) in favor of the `Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\OCI8\Middleware\InitializeSession`.

How should I setup the application with a new middleware? The documentation (https://symfony.com/bundles/DoctrineBundle/2.4.x/configuration.html#oracle-db) still show an old way.

I tried to use `driver_class` and `wrapper_class` options, but it does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
oracle.listener:
        class: Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\OCI8\Middleware\InitializeSession
        tags:
            - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: wrap }
```

I hope this can help you.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the new middleware system. Using `services.yaml` definition isn't enough if you have another database systems configured because you will get errors when use them.

Create a middleware extending the InitializeSession class and specifying the Oracle connections like here https://stackoverflow.com/a/76953879/3153254