# How to configure the Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\OCI8\Middleware\InitializeSession for a specific connection?

Tags: doctrine, symfony6

I have several connections to mysql and oracle databases and that solution "works" for all connections, and  it throws error on mysql. How do I restrict this to oracle connection only?

In deprected listener I can specify connection

my.oracle.listener:
class: Doctrine\DBAL\Event\Listeners\OracleSessionInit
tags:
- { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: postConnect, connection: oracleBase }

but in this new one, no.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the new [middleware system to specify Oracle connections](https://symfony.com/doc/current/DoctrineBundle/middlewares.html)
Extending the `InitializeSession` is enough

```php
<?php

namespace App\Middleware;

use Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Attribute\AsMiddleware;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\OCI8\Middleware\InitializeSession;

#[AsMiddleware(connections: ["database1", "database2"])]
class OracleMiddleware extends InitializeSession
{
}
```